# Joomla Kunena Forum Usergroup specific

Tags: joomla, forum

in my newest project i would like to have a usergroup specific forum.

**Specs:**

- Joomla 3.X
- Kunena

**Explanation Base:**

I have the usergroups:

- Group_A
- Group_B
- Group_C

These are parents of some subgroups:

- SubGroup_A1
- SubGroup_A2
- SubGroup_B1..

**How it should work:**

If a User from SubGroup_A1 clicks on the "Forum" button, he should be redirected to the forum subcategory SubGroup_A1 with its subcategories and topics.

**Question:**

Is there a way to realize this, without creating a specific Forum Button which is only visible for the logged in Users-Group? Maybe there is a better forum module which supports user group specific stuff?

Best Regards
Stefan Sprenger

Comment: You confused me with your question.

Comment: Glad to hear that ^^ Where do you have problems?

Comment: the button question confused me at first, but I read everything few more times and it was a little bit more clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign your desired permissions and access privileges for Kunena categories.

# Back-End -> Kunena -> Category Manager -> Category Permissions.

There are 2 options for Access Control Type: By Access Level or By User Groups.
After you assign your permissions, users that belongs to specific user groups will be able to see or participate to these categories that have access.

Comment: Sometimes it's very near